# Linear Algebra-inconsistent multiple choice question

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

Hello, a hint please?

I don't know the difference between these two equations, say for example,

$0x=4$ and 
$4x=0$
They both are inconsistent solutions , so what is the difference?

EDIT:
Perhaps I should have omitted the multiple choice question.My real question is the difference between a solution that has a co-efficient, but no value, and vice versa. In the end I do insert the multiple choice to allow other individuals to know where my question is derived from.

Comment: $4x=0$ has the solution $x=0$.  $0x=4$ has no solution, regardless of what $x$ is.

Comment: Thank you sir.$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$

Comment: I answered D.$$$$$$$$$

Answer (score 2):

An inconsistent system $A x = b$ is one that has no solution at all.

This is the 2D case. This can only happen if the rank of the matrix is one or zero and $b$ not on the line $Ax$ (rank one) or $b$ not zero (rank zero).

$A$ has rank 2 if $h\ne -2$, thus we can ignore b), c), e).

For a) and d) we have rank 1. If $k \ne 15$ the system has no solution and is therefore inconsistent. This is case d).

$0x = 4$ has no solution. $4x=0$ has one solution $x=0$. Only the former equation is inconsistent.

An example for the third major case would be $0x = 0$ which has infinite many solutions. This is not inconsistent.

Answer (score 1):

By doing Gaussian elimination
$$
\left[\begin{array}{cc|c}
1 & h & 3 \\
5 & -10 & k
\end{array}\right]
\xrightarrow{\ R_2\gets R_2-5R_1\ }
\left[\begin{array}{cc|c}
1 & h & 3 \\
0 & -10-5h & k-15
\end{array}\right]
$$
The system is inconsistent if and only if
$$
\begin{cases}
-10-5h=0\\[6px]
k-15\ne0
\end{cases}
$$
because only in this case the second equation reduces to the inconsistent $0=1$.

The condition is obviously equivalent to “$h=-2$ and $k\ne 15$”.  Note that we have “if and only if”, so we don't have to look at the other cases.

---

The equation $4x=0$ is not inconsistent: it has a single solution $x=0$. On the other hand, $0x=4$ is inconsistent, because for no $x$ you have $0x=4$.

In the case above, when $-10-5h\ne0$, the second equation becomes
$$
y=\frac{k-15}{-10-5h}
$$
so the system has solutions. In the case $-10-5h=0$ and $k-15=0$, the second equation tells you nothing, because it is $0=0$, which is true for any value you assign to $x$ and $y$. Thus the system has, in this case, infinitely many solutions.